# Передача примитивов по ссылке

Tags: java

Допустим, имеется `int x = 12;`. Есть ли возможность передать этот примитив по ссылке? Раньше думал, что для этой цели стоит использовать `Integer objX = Integer.valueOf(x);` , который затем можно передать по ссылке какому-нибудь методу. Но после передачи objX методу, который, например, увеличивал значения на 1, objX как был равен 12, так и остается.

Comment: Передавайте массив из одного элемента. Значение элемента можно менять как угодно. Изменения будут видны всем у кого есть ссылка на массив. Или передавайте экземпляр класса `class IntVar { public int value; }`.

Comment: главный вопрос - зачем? представьте ситуацию, что все объекты меняются по ссылке. значит все, у кого есть ссылка на объект может его изменить. а теперь представьте, что множество объектов имеет множество ссылок друг на друга и все что-то меняют. как вам такой мир? вы уверены, что среди 1млн строк кода вы сможете это отследить? посему все стремится именно к немутабельности. так меньше магии. классы-обертки для примитивов немутабельны, а , к примеру, стримы всегда возвращают новые коллекции либо массив, не меняя исходных данных. ваш вопорс должен звучать иначе: как избежать изменения по ссылке))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примитив по ссылке в Java передать нельзя, но можно создать класс-обёртку для примитива, и передавать ссылку на экземпляр такого класса.  `Integer` для этого не подходит, так как он является неизменяемым.

```java
public class MyInt {
    private int n;

    public MyInt(int n) { this.n = n; }

    public void setN(int m) { this.n = m; }
    public int getN() { return this.n; }

    public int preInc()  { return this.++n; }
    public int postInc() { return this.n++; }
}
```

```
MyInt mi = new MyInt(5);
foo(mi); // вызов метода, который изменит состояние
System.out.println(mi.getN()); // -> 6

static void foo(MyInt mi) {
    mi.preInc();
}
```

Другое дело, что минусов у такой реализации больше чем плюсов, самым главным из которых является потоконебезопасность и необходимость синхронизации при доступе к содержимому такого класса.

Comment: Проще передавать массив из одного элемента.